# How to set additional data to quote_item table from controller in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, quote, quoteitem

I have a controller with following code

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
    $item_id = $data['item_id'];
    $additionalOptions = $data['additional_options'];
    $itemFactory = $this->itemFactory->create()->load($item_id);
    $itemFactory->setAdditionalData($additionalOptions);
    $itemFactory->save();
```

but it throws following error while saving the quote item data as follows.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getStoreId() on
>   null in
>   vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Item/AbstractItem.php:144
>   Stack trace: #0

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to loading an the model `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item` with `quote_id` parameter, which I think won't work.

What you need to do here is, use the `quote_id` parameter to load `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote` model instance and then pick the right `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item` through it and set your data.

So this is what you need to do here.

```
$quote_id = $data['quote_id'];
$additionalOptions = $data['additional_options'];
$quote = $this->quoteRepository->getById($quote_id);

foreach ($quote->getItems() as $quoteItem) {
    $quoteItem->setAdditionalData($additionalOptions);
}

$quote->save();
```

Here `$this->quoteRepository` dependency should be `\Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface`. Also in the `foreach` loop, if you want to add further filtering for the quote item, then you should add it too.

Comment: $quote_id variable contains item_id so it that case it should work isn't it.?

Comment: I've updated the code, just have a look at it.